# If I randomly throw 10,000 balls to 4,000 buckets, what is the probability that at least one bucket contains more than 10 balls?

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

If I randomly throw 10,000 balls to 4,000 buckets, what is the probability that at least one bucket contains more than 10 balls?

I don't know how to even approach this.

A rough number is also accepted - it doesn't have to be precise.

Comment: For rough, use a few terms of Inclusion/Exclusion.

Comment: There's a tag `balls-in-bins`?????

Comment: I ran 10000 trials and 6689 of the trials had a bin with at least 10 balls in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with mean $2.5$ (the average number of balls per bucket).  Find the chance that one bucket has at most $10$ balls, raise to the  $4000$ power to have them all have ten or less, and subtract from $1$.  This is not exact-if one bucket is low that increases marginally the chance that another is high, but it will be very close.

Comment: How can I find the chance that one bucket has at most 10 balls?

Comment: You use the Poisson distribution and add the chances of $0$ through $10$.  Maybe "one bucket" should have been "a specific bucket" for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=(x_1, x_2 \cdots x_N)$ ($N=4000$) be the number of balls in each bucket; then $p_X(X)$ follows a multinomial distribution, with $\sum x_i = M$ ($M=10000$). Now, let $Y$ be $N$ iid Poisson variables with mean $\lambda$ -still not specified. Then the distribution of $Y$ conditioned on $\sum y_i = M$ is the same as our multinomial. Let $E$ be the event that all buckets have less than $K=10$ balls. Then

$$P(E) = P(y_i < K \mid \sum y_i = M)= \frac{P( \sum y_i = M \mid y_i < K )}{P(\sum y_i = M)} P(y_i<K)$$
where $y_i < K $ implies $\forall i$.

Each factor can be computed or approximated :

$$P(y_i<K)= \left[ g(K,\lambda) \right]^N$$

where  $$g(K,\lambda) = e^{-\lambda}  \sum_{x=0}^{K-1} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}=\frac{\Gamma(K,\lambda)}{\Gamma(K)}$$
Now, because the sum of iid Poisson variables is Poisson:
$$P(\sum y_i =M) = e^{-N\lambda} \frac{(N \lambda)^M}{M!}$$

The remaining factor  can be approximated using CLT as

$$P( \sum y_i = M \mid y_i < K ) \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi N \sigma^2}}\exp{\left(-\frac{M-N\mu}{2N \sigma^2}\right)}$$
where $\mu$,$\sigma^2$ are the mean and variance of a Poisson with parameter $\lambda$ 
truncated to $0,K-1$.

A good selection of $\lambda$ would be that that gives $\mu N=M$, because that would probably produce a good approximation.